# Android: Pass an integer from NumberPicker to another activity

Tags: java, android

I am using the built in NumberPicker to have the user choose a number. Then the user will hit the "OK" button to confirm and the resulting action will open up another activity. I want the number that the user chooses to be passed through to the other activity when the user hits the "OK" button. I have done buttons that result in opening up a new activity and I know that the NumberPicker has a getValue() and you can pass stuff through with putExtra(), but I am not sure how to combine those with the onClick method. How do I go about doing this?

```
public class Source1 extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);
...(NumberPicker code)
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int x = ((NumberPicker) v).getValue();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Destination.class);
    intent.putExtra("VarName", x);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

This is the xml for my button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Id_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/numberPicker1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="methodName"
    android:text="@string/Ok" />
```

That was my attempt. Is this right/what needs to change? Do I even need the onClick in the button code since I am using the onClick method in the class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your code as to get selected value from `NumberPicker` on Button click:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    NumberPicker numPicker = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.NumberPicker_id);
    int x = numPicker.getValue();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Destination.class);
    intent.putExtra("VarName", x);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: @imran khan Ok, so I made the changes including the removing the onClick from the xml (leaving just the onClick method in the class). In the Destination class I did the declaration of Intent intent = getIntent(); and int intValue = intent.getIntExtra("VarName", ???); My question is what do I put where the question marks are? The compiler does not like just "getExtra" it wants me to add "getBundleExtra", "getStringExtra", etc. But how can I choose a value when it will constantly be dependent upon the user from the previous activity?

Comment: @lord_sneed : put any default integer value as second param in `intent.getIntExtra("VarName", ANY_DEFAULT_INTEGER_VALUE);`

Answer (score 2):

> Is this right/what needs to change?

The best way to test whether its right is: try to read `VarName` in `Destination`. But see imran khan's answer.

> Do I even the onClick in the button code since I am using the onClick method in the class?

No, you should choose one or the other. Either use:

1. `onClick="methodName"` in the XML, with `public void methodName(View v) {}` in `Source1`
2. `implement OnClickListener` and use `numberPicker.setOnClickListener(this);`.